# Combining JOIN and ARRAYFORMULA doesn't work

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

```
Column B   Column B    Desired output
Some       Thing       Some Thing
Any                    Any (with NO blank space because of blank cell)
No         Thing       No Thing
           Thing       Thing (with no leading space either)
```

I have tried this: `={"COPY-PASTE" ; ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(" "; SAND; $B$2; $C$2))}` - with no succes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:B),,999^99))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: What is the 999^99 about?

Comment: 999'99 is "realy big number" - means nothing. can be 8888888 or 5000, but not 3 coz query wont join stuff properly